# sed: how to disable autoprinting via script file instead of using the -n switch?

Tags: sed

I had a confusion with this topic between switching between command line and script file interface. I had a nice script written out in the command line that worked, but as soon as I wanted to save it to a .sed file, I remembered I could no longer use the `-n`. I tried using '!d' flag, but I'm not getting the same output. My question:
Is there a way to put the `-n` in a .sed file, or some other way to stop the automatic printing when I'm in script file interface? I hate to have to convert from protecting my script from the shell to not protecting it, but I guess there is no way around it?

Comment: This question would be much easier to understand with some specifics - are you saying you can't use the `-n` and `-f` command line options together for some reason?

Comment: I'm wanting to stop automatic printing when I'm writing a .sed file. I have only used -n on the command line to do this. However, I'm unfamiliar with how to do this in a .sed file because we don't need to protect our sed script from the shell etc... Overall: how do I stop automatic printing when I'm writing a .sed file?

Comment: Are you planning to use the file with `sed -f` from the command line, or using `#!/usr/bin/sed -f` at the top of the file? Either way, replacing the `-f` with `-nf` should work.

Comment: Yes, I plan on using 'sed -f myfile.sed filein'

Comment: Yes, I need the whole script in the .sed file. Only thing on the command line should be 'sed -f myfile.sed filein'. I want to integrate the turning off the automatic printing in my .sed file, and not on the command line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard (POSIX) way is to have `#n` at the start of the script. They have to be the first two bytes of the script.

That precludes the use of a she-bang, that's only to be used for scripts run as `sed -f the-script` (note that she-bangs are not POSIX and POSIX doesn't specify the path of utilities), but as @Kusalananda said, when using a she-bang, you can always do:

```
#! /path/to/sed -nf
```

If you want to make an executable `sed` script on systems that support she-bangs with arguments (most).

Note that the `#n` also works on the command line as in:

```
sed '#n
  s/foo/bar/p'
```

And you can add more text after like:

```
#no default output
s/foo/bar/p
```

Or:

```
#nifty way to turn -n on
s/foo/bar/p
```

Actually, that's something to bear in mind to avoid turning `-n` on by mistake. It's a good idea to use a space after `#` in comments for that (and for legibility).

```
# no, I don't want to turn -n on
s/foo/bar/
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the `#n` doesn't _replace_ the `#!` line for an executable `sed` script, and you can't use both. Hence a `sed` script with `#n` needs to be run with `sed -f` explicitly on the command line, as far as I can see at least.

Answer (score 2):

`sed [-e] 'command'` and `sed -f /path/to/script` behave exactly the same way with respect to the `-n` switch.  If you want to execute a `sed` script and turn off the "print-by-default" behavior, use `sed -n -f /path/to/script.sed /path/to/input`.

Answer (score 2):

You will either have to run the `sed` script using

```
$ sed -n -f script.sed
```

or change the `#!` ("hash-bang") line in the script to something like

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -nf
```

and run it with

```
$ ./script.sed
```